# Uniform implies pointwise convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

I had a question to show a sequence of functions  $(x_n)$ in $C[0,1]$ (equipped with a metric $d$) does not contain a uniformly convergent subsequence. $$ x_n(t) = \ n(1-nt) \ \ \ \ \ \  \forall \ t\le \frac1n\\= \ 0 \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall  \ t\gt \frac1n $$

I managed to show than an arbitrary subsequence $(x_{k})$ does not converge pointwise (and this was marked as correct).
My argument then was that:

- Uniform Conv. $\Rightarrow$ Pointwise Conv.
- So  ~Pointwise Conv.  $\Rightarrow$ ~Uniform Conv.

So then $(x_k)$ does not uniformly converge.
Is this logic correct?

My corrector marked it as wrong and wrote "Uniform is **much** stronger than pointwise convergence".

(This isn't a tirade against my corrector, i'm just genuinely trying to find out if/where I've gone wrong)

Comment: Sounds fine to me.

Comment: I would guess that the corrector just misread and overlooked the tildes in "~Pointwise Conv. $\Rightarrow$ ~Uniform Conv.". Though in the context, that would be surprising too.